# How to prevent double click for keycode 9 i.e. on tab press in jquery

Tags: jquery

```
if (e.keyCode === 9) {
        // tab      
       
      }
```

I am not able to find any useful answer for this. After searching alot I am asking here. I want to disable double click after a tab key is pressed. Help me with useful answer. Thanks in advance

Comment: double click for what? On an element? window? We need more context on what is going on here.

Comment: you want to user wait untill first click complete or what?

Comment: means once I pressed tab I wont be able to press  it further - @epascarello

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a class to your body and check it when you press tab

```js
$(document).keydown(function(objEvent) {
  if (objEvent.keyCode == 9) {  //tab pressed
    if ($('body').hasClass("ctrlTab")){
      objEvent.preventDefault(); // stops its action
    } else {
      $('body').addClass('ctrlTab');
      console.log('tab once');
    } 
   }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body></body>
```

Comment: this is not working as this will prevent it from clicking even once which I dont want. I want something that will allow it to press only once and after that not allow it to press again - @The_Death_Raw

Comment: Check my edit plz and upvote + validate if its what you need :) @jiga

Comment: This is what I needed. Thanks @The_Death_Raw